# navigation bar not showing drop down content on hover (CSS)

Tags: html, css

hi i am creating a **drop down menu** where everything is working fine. Accept when i hide my **drop down block** it does not shows up on **hover** again.Can anyone help what is wrong here.??

**HTML-:**

```
<div id="nav_wrapper">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#">maths</a>
           <ul class="one">
              <li><a href="#">real number</a></li> 
           </ul>
      </li> 
      <li><a href="#">english</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hindi</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">french</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">german</a></li>    
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS-:**

```
#nav_wrapper
{


    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 100px;

}
#nav_wrapper ul{
 list-style-type: none;   
 }

 #nav_wrapper ul li{
     outline: 1px solid white;
     width: 160px;
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     background: black;

 }


 #nav_wrapper ul li a{
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 25px;
     width: 160px;
     padding-top: 7px;
     color: #DAA520;


 }

 #nav_wrapper ul ul.one
 {
     display: none;
 }
 #nav_wrapper ul li a:hover {
      color: wheat; 

 }


 #nav_wrapper ul li a:hover > ul.one{
     display: block;

 }
```

Now when i hover on **MATHS** my **real number** block (drop down) not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its next element not the child .so try this  `a:hover + ul.one`

***[css selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)***

**Explaination**

1. `>` used for a child `parent > child`
2. `+` used for the next element `firstelement + nextelemnt`

**example snippet for `parent> child`**

```css
.child,.second{
  display:none;
  }

.first:hover > .child{
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div  class="first">hover me
<a class="child"> child open</a>
</div>

<div class="second" > i m a next element</div>
```

**example snippet for `firstelement + next element`**

```css
.child,.second{
  display:none;
  }

.first:hover + .second{
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div  class="first">hover me
<a class="child"> child open</a>
</div>

<div class="second" > i m a next element</div>
```

```css
#nav_wrapper
{


    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 100px;

}
#nav_wrapper ul{
 list-style-type: none;   
 }

 #nav_wrapper ul li{
     outline: 1px solid white;
     width: 160px;
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     background: black;

 }


 #nav_wrapper ul li a{
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 25px;
     width: 160px;
     padding-top: 7px;
     color: #DAA520;


 }

 #nav_wrapper ul ul.one
 {
     display: none;
 }
 #nav_wrapper ul li a:hover {
      color: wheat; 

 }


 #nav_wrapper ul li a:hover + ul.one{
     display: block;

 }
```

```html
<div id="nav_wrapper">
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">maths</a>
                           <ul class="one">
                              <li><a href="#">real number</a></li> 
                           </ul>
                       </li> 
                       <li><a href="#">english</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">hindi</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">french</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">german</a></li>    
                   </ul>

           </div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks it worked can you explain me a little more why we used + here instead of >

Comment: @TusharSharma see updated answer. i was added explanation and example also

Comment: `>` is `immediate child selector` not only child selector, and `+` is `adjacent sibling selector`.

Answer (score 1):

hi can you try this code, actually make you css code `a:hover + ul.one` and i have given the demo link
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a4pnsLf9/)